# Do higher levels of Explore give better chances of rarer Traitstones?

Tags: gems-of-war

Do higher levels of Explore give better chances of rarer Traitstones?

It says "Each battle has increased chance for Arcane Traitstones"

...

But, I'm not sure if higher levels boost the chances, or if it just boosts what it says, Gold, Mythstones, and Tokens.

So, if I want to get Traitstones faster, do I just keep redoing the lowest level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Explore Difficulty screen says what amplifications of gold, mythstones, and tokens you will get.

[image: Explore Difficulty]

Every battle in Explore always gets you a traitstone.

The traitstone drop rates for non-boss battles are not officially posted, but, from information I can gather, the rates don't change with difficulty, and are: 60% minor, 30% major, 8% runic, 1.5% arcane, 0.5% celestial.

The rate of Arcane Traitstones **only** are also increased at higher difficulty levels for the Mini-Boss battle. In particular, at difficulty 11 and 12, Mini-Boss battles give Arcanes with 100% chance. (Unofficial drop rates for Mini-Boss battles, from Difficulty 1 through Difficulty 12: 7%, 9%, 20%, 25%, 30%, 41%, 51%, 61%, 71%, 81%, 100%, 100%.)

(For people curious about token rarities and quantities, I've put together [a spreadsheet for that information](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WLxA1CZaclyk60P-BRx1F-cx4z0185FAFGDVs-GAD0A). One of the guild leaders I work with requested that information, so I thought it might help others too. Again, 100% unofficial.)

The Mythic Boss battle always gives an Arcane (no matter what difficulty). But higher difficulty explores (which give more mythstones) help there too, since you need to collect 100 mythstones to unlock a Mythic Boss battle.

---

Note that you can hoard mythstones: just because you unlock the Mythic Boss battle for a given explore run, does not mean you have to spend it! Just do an explore run in a different kingdom (especially ones with mythstone bonuses) and hoard up mythstones for doing the Mythic Boss battles for the kingdoms you want.

For example, say you are trying to get arcanes from Whitehelm. You could do all the mythstone-bonus kingdoms explore runs at difficulty 12 (to maximise the mythstones you get), without doing the Mythic Boss battle in any of them, then go and do several Whitehelm runs at a lower difficulty level if you wish.

(Why? Mythic Boss battles are all-or-nothing: if you lose, you lose the mythstones spent to unlock that battle. So unless you are confident of a difficulty 12 win, a lower difficulty level is more likely to be fruitful.)

Comment: Thanks! ... So, the regular Explore battles, do, or don't have increased Arcane chance per level?

Comment: For non-boss battles, I have not observed any increased chances of Arcanes at higher difficulty levels. I checked with another experienced player to see if their experiences lined up with mine, and they agreed.

Comment: Thanks again! ... So, the non-Boss drop rate for Arcanes is, what? You've already answered my main question, so it's fine if you don't know. ... Currently, it seems like, if I want to grind Arcanes, right now, when I can't beat level 5 consistently, might be to just grind Level 1... ... Unless I / we get some probability math proves me wrong, that's what I'll be doing...

Comment: The traitstone drop rates are not officially posted, but, from information I can gather, for normal battles it is: 60% minor, 30% major, 8% runic, 1.5% arcane, 0.5% celestial.

Comment: That's very useful! ... Maybe edit the info into your answer? ... And I guess we dunno exactly by how much Mini and Mythic Boss battles increase the chance of Arcanes, per level... Meh. I'll just grind low levels for 'em.

Comment: I added the arcane drop rates for Mini-Boss battles into the answer. I hope this helps. :-) (The generic drop rates don't relate specifically to explore, so I don't know if it's useful to put into the answer.)